# how to assign a dynamic value to tooltip in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I Need to assign the tooltip text dynamically in angualr I'm using  something like below which is not working.

```
      <h5>Contract Name </h5>
             <span tooltip="{{ContractName}}" class="fac-tooltip tip-left">
                <input
                       type="text"
                       name="ContractName"
                       id="ContractName"
                       [readonly]="true"
                       value= "{{ContractName}}"
                    > 
                    </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom `tooltip` directive and use that.

see the example of code [here](https://github.com/kamrankhatti/angular-tooltip-directive)

usage:

```
<a 
  href="https://google.com" 
  tooltip="Put your tooltip text here">
   This is tooltip with default placement
</a>

Tooltip with placement top
<p 
  placement="top"
  tooltip="Put your tooltip text here">
  This is tooltip with placement top
</p>
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some meta attributes for tooltip.

```
 <span data-toggle="tooltip"
               data-placement="bottom" 
               data-html="true"
               title="{{ContractName}}" 
               class="fac-tooltip tip-left">
            <input
                   type="text"
                   name="ContractName"
                   id="ContractName"
                   [readonly]="true"
                   value= "{{ContractName}}"
                > 
        </span>
```